# Testing angular service fails with service.config is undefined in main.js

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-runner

I have written a simple service to dynamically fetch configuration for our Angular app. Now I am writing unit tests but am at a bit of a loss, as to where I am going wrong, since I am simply trying to test for the value of one config parameter, but Karma tells me that the function I am calling is undefined.

This is the service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfigService {
  private appConfig: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  async loadAppConfig(): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const response = await this.http.get('/assets/data/appConfig.json')
        .toPromise()
      this.appConfig = response;
      return this.appConfig;
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(err)
    }
  }

  get config(): any {
    return this.appConfig;
  }
}
```

And these are the unit tests. The first one succeeds, second one fails however:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppConfigService } from './app-config.service';

describe('AppConfigService', () => {
  let service: AppConfigService;
  let client: HttpClient;

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new AppConfigService(client)
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should output correct apiUri', () => {
    expect(service.config.apiUri).toBe('http://api:8080/query');
    });
});
```

This is Karma's output:

```
Firefox 102.0 (Linux x86_64) AppConfigService should output correct apiUri FAILED
    TypeError: service.config is undefined in main.js (line 46)
    501/</<@main.js:46:9
    invoke@polyfills.js:382:26
    onInvoke@vendor.js:102041:39
    invoke@polyfills.js:381:52
    run@polyfills.js:144:43
    runInTestZone@vendor.js:102321:34
    wrapTestInZone/<@vendor.js:102336:20
    <Jasmine>
    invokeTask@polyfills.js:416:31
    runTask@polyfills.js:188:47
    drainMicroTaskQueue@polyfills.js:592:35
```

Please let me know if there is any additional info I can provide. Haven't succeded finding cues in the documentation so far as to what I have written wrong.

Comment: You never call `loadAppConfig()`  in your tests

Comment: Hi @MatthieuRiegler, thanks for pointing that out. If I call `loadAppConfig()` in the `before()` clause, the error remains and I get `Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _this.http is undefined in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js (line 83)` in addition to that.